# Play 1.3 Event Stream implementation

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x, server-sent-events

So I've been trying to implement a proper EventStream solution using Play Framework 1.3, however I just can't get it to work properly. An exception keeps getting thrown but I'm not sure what the cause is.

Can anyone provide an example implementation or point me in the direction of one?

This is the method I have in my controller.

```
public static void stream() {
    response.contentType = "text/event-stream";
    response.encoding = "UTF-8";
    response.status = 200;
    response.chunked = true;

    // a record of the last ID that this request... requested
    Long lastId = 0L;

    // since this request has only been initiated, the first thing to do is return a list of whats in the queue
    List<F.IndexedEvent> archive = StreamQueue.getRecentNotifications(lastId);
    if (!archive.isEmpty()) {
        // write that list out in the response
        response.writeChunk(//a string representing the entire list as a single event);
        // update out internal reference to the lastId
        lastId = archive.get(archive.size() - 1).id;
    }

    // keep this connection alive
    while (true) {
        // await the promise of more notifications for the stream
        List<F.IndexedEvent<StreamQueue.Notification>> notifications = await(StreamQueue.getNextNotification(lastId));
        // for each notification, write it out as a separate event
        for (int i = 0; i < notifications.size(); i++) {
            response.writeChunk(//a string representing a single event using notifications.get(i));
            // update out internal reference to the lastId
            lastId = notifications.get(i).id;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my implementation of the queue StreamQueue.java:

```
public class StreamQueue {
    final ArchivedEventStream<StreamQueue.Notification> notifications = new ArchivedEventStream<StreamQueue.Notification>(100);
    static StreamQueue instance = null;

    public static StreamQueue get() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new StreamQueue();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    // the method to call when I want to send an event
    public static void alert(Notification.Type type, Object... args){
        get().addMessage((String) args[0]);
    }

    public static F.Promise<java.util.List<F.IndexedEvent<Notification>>> getNextNotification(Long lastId) {
        return get().getNotificationsStream().nextEvents(lastId);
    }

    public static java.util.List<F.IndexedEvent> getRecentNotifications(Long lastId) {
        return get().getNotificationsStream().availableEvents(lastId);
    }

    public ArchivedEventStream<StreamQueue.Notification> getNotificationsStream() {
        return notifications;
    }

    private void addMessage(String message){
        notifications.publish(new StreamQueue.MessageEvent(message));
    }


    public static abstract class Notification extends F.IndexedEvent {
        public enum Type {
            ISSUE,
            MESSAGE;
        }

        final public Type type;
        final public Long timestamp;

        public Notification(Type type) {
            super(type);
            this.type = type;
            this.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public String toJson() {
            return new JSONSerializer().exclude("class").serialize(this);
        }
    }

    public static class MessageEvent extends StreamQueue.Notification {
        public final String message;

        public MessageEvent(String message) {
            super(Type.MESSAGE);
            this.message = message;
        }

        public String toJson() {
            return new JSONSerializer().include("message").exclude("*").serialize(this);
        }
    }

}
```

And finally, here's the exception I'm getting:

```
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /stream

Execution exception
InvocationTargetException occured : null

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:230)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:524)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:475)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:451)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:446)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:160)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at controllers.StreamController.stream(StreamController.java)
    ... 6 more
```

The exception seems to be thrown as a result of `ArchivedEventStream.nextEvents(...)` which I'm calling from `StreamQueue.getNextNotification(...)`. The cause appears to be a `Long` being cast to a `Map` but at no point do I attempt to do that.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**UPDATE**
So I tried my project in Play 1.2.5 and the streaming works perfectly. However, the project demands we use Play 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is at bottom of the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

I think you are trying to cast `Notification.timestamp` to map in `StreamController`.

Comment: The timestamp actually isn't being used (a left over relic from previous code) but the exception seems to be happening inside ArchivedEventStream.nextEvents(...);